# Rails 5 - build AR query from arbitrary hash of keys and values on associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, hash, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to parse URLs and store unique Pages. Thanks to sites like Youtube which build unique pages based on query parameters (and not just on the URI path portion), I need to discriminate on the full url, not just the path part. (I'm ignoring the fragment section for now, I don't think this will be useful for my application)

Here's a sample of the data I'm working with

```
{
"url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jExdUIc49s?&ab_channel=PokerStaples",
  "decoded": {
    "scheme": "https",
    "host": {
      "prefix": "www",
      "suffix": "youtube.com"
    },
    "path": "watch",
    "queries": [
      {
        "query": "v",
        "value": "0jExdUIc49s?"
      },
      {
        "query": "ab_channel",
        "value": "PokerStaples"
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

**Step 1**

Build a query like this, but dynamic based on the queries from the supplied URL.

```
p = Page.joins(:page_queries)
        .where(path: 'watch', domain: @domain)
        .where(page_queries: {query: 'v', value: '0jExdUIc49s?'})
        .first_or_create
```

PageQueries is as you'd expect, Page has_many PageQueries (attributes page_id, query, value)

I think I'm getting close by creating a hash, but obviously I'm missing something:

```
pq = { 'v':'0jExdUIc49s?' } 

p = Page.joins(:page_queries)
        .where(path: 'watch', domain: @domain)
        .where(page_queries: pq)
        .first_or_create
```

Here's the output:

> p = Page.joins(:page_queries).where(path: 'watch', domain:
>   @domain).where(page_queries: pq)     Page Load (1.4ms)  SELECT
>   "pages".* FROM "pages" INNER JOIN "page_queries" ON
>   "page_queries"."page_id" = "pages"."id" WHERE "pages"."path" = ? AND
>   "pages"."domain_id" = 162 AND "page_queries"."v" = ?  [["path",
>   "watch"], ["v", "0jExdUIc49s?"]]
>
> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column:
>   page_queries.v: SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages" INNER JOIN
>   "page_queries" ON "page_queries"."page_id" = "pages"."id" WHERE
>   "pages"."path" = ? AND "pages"."domain_id" = 162 AND
>   "page_queries"."v" = ?

*Any ideas?*

I've been banging my head against this problem for hours. Your help is GREATLY appreciated.

**Step 2**

Each Domain record also has_many Discriminators - those queries which discriminate a unique result.  (IE, utm_ queries are used for tracking and of no use in this application).  We add these in as we find domains which require query values to define a unique page.

For YouTube like we've been using, "v" is the important parameter, though for my testing, I added a second one.

I pull them into an array:

```
@domain.discriminators.pluck(:query)
[ 
  [0] "v",
  [1] "test"
]
```

..and then the goal is to use the merge of the "discriminators" and the supplied queries to create and use only unique Page records with useful categories.

I haven't got this far yet, but once I get past step 1 I don't think it will be much of a problem.

Thanks!

---

Per request - The basic schema & relations

```
Domain
  has_many :pages
  has_many :discriminators
  t.string   "suffix"
  t.string   "prefix"
  t.string   "connection"

Discriminator
  belongs_to :domain
   t.string   "query"
   t.integer  "domain_id"

Page
  belongs_to :domain
  has_many :page_queries
  t.string   "path"
  t.integer  "domain_id"

PageQuery
  belongs_to :page
  t.string   "query"
  t.string   "value"
  t.integer  "page_id"
```

Now, the fugly way to (almost) solve my problem!  I really hope someone can come up with some ninja Ruby to save me from this fate. (I'm not writing this in as an answer because I can't in good conscience call this an answer. It's ducktape.)

```
@url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jExdUIc49s?&ab_channel=PokerStaples"
uri = URI(@url)
@queries = uri.query.split('&')
@pq = {}
@queries.each do |q| 
  k = q.split('=').first
  v = q.split('=').last
  @pq.store(k.to_sym, v)
end
@request = "Page.joins(:page_queries).where(path: 'watch', domain: @domain)"
@pq.each {|q, v| @request << ".where(page_queries: {query: '#{q}', value:'#{v}'})"}
eval(@request)
```

Fugly! Here's hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: Can you share you db table structure once.

Comment: `pq = { 'v':'0jExdUIc49s?' } ` is not valid Hash syntax.